# Как почистить local lfs\temp на PC?

Tags: git

local lfs\temp на моем компе достиг 370Gb это все свободное место... `git lfs prune` не помагает

Comment: `git clean` - стирает всё, что не нужно. `git repack` - сжимает оставшееся.

Comment: @AlexGlebe вроде как `git lfs clean` помог, но не пойму пока разницу

Comment: Почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50135844/what-does-git-do-when-we-do-git-gc-git-prune там много расписано что такое сборка мусора `git gc` и чем отличается от `git prune`.